# incorrect syntax near 's' vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, user-input, sqlcommand

I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near 's'`. Error appears after inputting data in SQL sometimes it doesn't appear but when same characters will input the error appears.
Error lined in the `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
conn.Open()
comm = New SqlCommand("Insert into Admins(Firstname, Lastname, Birthday, Contact, Email, Address, Username, Password, SecurityQ1, SecurityQ2, SecurityI1, SecurityI2, SecurityA1, SecurityA2, Type) values ('" & BunifuMetroTextbox1.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox2.Text & "','" & BunifuDatepicker1.Value & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox3.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox8.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox9.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox4.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox5.Text & "','" & BunifuDropdown1.selectedValue & "','" & BunifuDropdown2.selectedValue & "','" & BunifuDropdown1.selectedIndex & "','" & BunifuDropdown2.selectedIndex & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox6.Text & "','" & BunifuMetroTextbox7.Text & "','" & admintype & "')", conn)
affector = comm.ExecuteNonQuery
conn.Close()
```

Comment: That happens when you don't escape your user input. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Indeed. Somewhere you've got a string like "Mother's Maiden Name"—think what happens when the single quote in that terminates the single quote you've wrapped around it in your hardcoded SQL statement. [Prepare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)!

Comment: Never concat strings to make a SQL query; use Parameters.  Never ever store passwords as plain text.  hash them.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com